# how to config DOH with coreDNS?

Tags: dns, coredns, doh

@ https://coredns.io/community/.
I can see the following configuration on the official website, but this does not provide HTTPS service, it is a forwarding.

I can't find how to configure the doh.

And for DNS over HTTP/2 (DoH) use:
https://example.org {
    whoami
}

Comment: https://.:443 {
    tls crt.crt key.key
}

Comment: Did you got it working?

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz yes，it is work
https://.:443 { 
    tls crt.crt key.key 
}

Comment: so coredns works as a resolver as a https dns client ? In other dns resolver client we put doh service uri that has `/dns-query` like of cooudflared. I used dnscrypt proxy

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz yes!

Answer (score 0):

https://.:443 tls://.:853 {

```
tls plugin/tls/test_cert.pem plugin/tls/test_key.pem plugin/tls/test_ca.pem

cache

forward . 8.8.8.8:53 {
    prefer_udp
}
```

}